# Custom Dropdown with left and right textbox

Tags: jquery

I found a dropdown but I can't find a dropdown like this anywhere, could you anyone please help me to create a dropdown like this?

[image: This is the dropdown]

Comment: Looks like a custom code to me...

Comment: yes but i need to create a drop-down like this,is there any way ?

Comment: I am doing it buddy...

Comment: Can you check man?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a custom code. Just a prototype of how it might work:

```js
$(function () {
  $(".dropdown-trigger").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest(".dropdown-container").toggleClass("open");
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
}
.dropdown-container {
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-container input {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100px;
}
.dropdown-container a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 4px 5px;
  color: #333;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  border-top: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  display: none;
}
.dropdown-menu a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 5px;
}
.dropdown-container.open .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <input type="text" />
  <a href="" class="dropdown-trigger">&#x25BC;</a>
  <input type="text" />
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 4</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 6</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 7</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 8</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 9</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Item 10</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's fine,but i need to populate the selected option to the textboxes

Comment: @AchuS You need to do that yourself. Then you also need to update the text box values. I know getting the UI is tough, so I helped you. Your question now already has 3 close votes that you haven't added initial work. So this is gonna be your task mate. It's like you are asking me to make the whole Select 2 plugin customised. Not fair na? `:)`

Comment: @AchuS Do you wanna accept this answer and ask another question, that's a follow up to this for values if you find it difficult?

Comment: yea sure,but i already made this by my code,i posted this for just wants to know if this dropdown via any plugin or not

Comment: @AchuS No mate. There's no plugin that will do this for you. It's a custom code.

Answer (score 0):

By using this function on li onclick i made this dropdown

```
function setSizess(param){
var id = $(param).attr('id');
var width = $(param).attr('rel');
var height = $(param).attr('ref');
if(height=="custom"){
    $(".banner-sizes").slideUp('fast');
    var width = $('#banner_'+id+'_height').val(height);
    var height = $('#banner_'+id+'_width').val(height);
    if(width!=null || height!=null){
        $('#banner_'+id+'_height').val('');
        $('#banner_'+id+'_width').val('');
    }
    $('#banner_'+id+'_width').focus();
}else{
    $('#banner_'+id+'_height').val(height);
    $('#banner_'+id+'_width').val(width);
}

function enableClick(param){
var id = $(param).attr('id');
var abc = id.substring(id.indexOf('_') +1);
$('#'+id).click(function(){
    $('.close_banner_'+abc).show();
});

$(".showsizebox").live('click', function(){
$(".banner-sizes").on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(".banner-sizes").slideUp('fast');
});
```

[image: result dropdpown]